# Select first level by value and second level by index on a MultiIndex DataFrame

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have a MultiIndex-based Pandas DataFrame. Index are RANK, latitude, longitude, time and REF_ID while column is FFDI.

```
                                                   FFDI
RANK    latitude    longitude   time      REF_ID    
  1     -39.20000   140.80000   1973-04-02  0   5.40000
                    140.83786   1973-04-02  1   5.40000
                    140.87572   1973-04-02  2   5.40000
                    140.91359   1973-04-02  3   5.40000
                    140.95145   1973-04-02  4   5.40000
                    140.98930   1973-04-02  5   5.40000
                    141.02716   1973-04-02  6   5.40000
                    141.06502   1973-05-31  7   5.40000
                    141.10289   1973-05-31  8   5.50000
                    141.14075   1973-05-31  9   6.00000
                    141.17860   1973-05-31  10  6.40000
                    141.21646   1973-05-31  11  6.80000
                    141.25432   1973-05-31  12  7.70000
                    141.29219   1973-05-31  13  7.90000
                    141.33005   1973-05-31  14  7.00000
                    141.36790   1973-05-31  15  6.60000
                    141.40576   1973-05-31  16  6.10000
                    141.44362   1973-05-31  17  5.00000
                    141.48149   1973-05-31  18  4.40000
    ...     ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
    5   -33.90000   148.90205   1972-12-24  36082   35.70000
                    148.93991   1974-11-12  36083   36.30000
                    148.97778   1974-11-12  36084   35.90000
                    149.01564   1973-11-20  36085   36.80000
                    149.05350   1973-11-20  36086   37.00000
                    149.09135   1974-11-12  36087   35.60000
                    149.12921   1973-01-03  36088   35.90000
                    149.16708   1973-01-03  36089   34.40000
                    149.20494   1973-01-03  36090   32.90000
                    149.24280   1973-01-03  36091   32.20000
                    149.28065   1973-01-03  36092   32.30000
                    149.31851   1973-01-03  36093   32.20000
                    149.35638   1973-01-03  36094   30.20000
                    149.39424   1973-11-20  36095   28.60000
                    149.43210   1973-11-20  36096   28.70000
                    149.46996   1973-11-20  36097   29.10000
                    149.50781   1973-11-20  36098   30.10000
                    149.54568   1973-11-20  36099   30.80000
                    149.58354   1973-01-09  36100   30.60000
                    149.62140   1973-01-09  36101   30.10000
        
180560 rows × 1 columns
```

I want to select on the first level `RANK`=1 (value), and the second level `latitude` = first index (i.e. value=-39.20000). So the output will look like:

```
                                                   FFDI
RANK    latitude    longitude   time      REF_ID    
  1     -39.20000   140.80000   1973-04-02  0   5.40000
                    140.83786   1973-04-02  1   5.40000
                    140.87572   1973-04-02  2   5.40000
                    140.91359   1973-04-02  3   5.40000
                    140.95145   1973-04-02  4   5.40000
                    140.98930   1973-04-02  5   5.40000
                    141.02716   1973-04-02  6   5.40000
                    141.06502   1973-05-31  7   5.40000
                    141.10289   1973-05-31  8   5.50000
                    141.14075   1973-05-31  9   6.00000
                    141.17860   1973-05-31  10  6.40000
                    141.21646   1973-05-31  11  6.80000
                    141.25432   1973-05-31  12  7.70000
                    141.29219   1973-05-31  13  7.90000
                    141.33005   1973-05-31  14  7.00000
                    141.36790   1973-05-31  15  6.60000
                    141.40576   1973-05-31  16  6.10000
                    141.44362   1973-05-31  17  5.00000
                    141.48149   1973-05-31  18  4.40000
```

Edit: can selection on the second level based on index range, e.g. from the first one to the fourth one)?

Answer (score 0):

Try with `reset_index`, then `slice`

```
s = df.reset_index()
out = df[((s['Rank']==1) & (s['latitude']>=-39.2) & s['latitude']<=-39.33422)).tolist()].copy()
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I set index based on the second level (latitude)?

Comment: @alextc what you mean set index here

Comment: What I meant is that I would like to select level one by its label (RANK=1) and level two by its index range (e.g. the first coordinate to fourth coordinate) instead of its label (from -39.2 to -39.-33422). Sorry I have just edited my question to use index range.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Can I use the indexer on the latitude coordinate, e.g. something like [0:5], which means from the first to the fourth?

Comment: @alextc for multiple index , i will recommend reset_index , since it will create more headache than the simple index